# PHP Determine the starting characters of a string and length of a string then assign values to variable based upon the results

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have this if/elseif statement where if $DiscountDescription is not empty, then I search to see if it starts with an "e", "E", "A", and has either 12 characters, or 10 characters. Two other scenarios are 18 characters with 2 dashes, and 9 characters that are all numerical.

The code looks right to me, but it doesn't appear to be working. Any ideas?

```
$DiscountDescription = $_order->getDiscountDescription();

if ($DiscountDescription != '') {
    if (substr($DiscountDescription,0,1 == "e") && strlen($DiscountDescription == 12)){
        $_order->setDiscountDescription('Gift Cards ' . $DiscountDescription);
    }
    elseif (substr($DiscountDescription,0,1 == "E") && strlen($DiscountDescription == 10)){
        $_order->setDiscountDescription('Gift Cards ' . $DiscountDescription);
    }
    elseif (substr($DiscountDescription,0,1 == "A") && strlen($DiscountDescription == 10)){
        $_order->setDiscountDescription('Gift Cards ' . $DiscountDescription);
    }
    elseif (strlen($DiscountDescription == 18) && substr_count($DiscountDescription,'-' == 2)){
        $_order->setDiscountDescription('Gift Cards ' . $DiscountDescription);
    }
    elseif (strlen($DiscountDescription == 9) && ctype_digit($DiscountDescription)){
        $_order->setDiscountDescription('Gift Cards ' . $DiscountDescription);
    }

    //$_order->setDiscountDescription('Gift Cards ' . $DiscountDescription);
}
```

Comment: `strlen($DiscountDescription == 10)` __must be__ `strlen($DiscountDescription) == 10`. __Same__ for `substr_count`

Comment: @u_mulder And `substr()`...

Comment: You're putting all of your == inside of the functions instead of outside.. you want it more like substr_count( $var, "-") == 2 .  and strlen( $var ) == 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone else said it looks like you are doing comparisons in the length check which won't work. You want to get the length and then compare it to an integer.

As a best practice you should also try to use strict comparisons `===` instead of `==`.